# Application logs are logged into mail file

Tags: shell

I have created a script and this script is running infinitely and logged the messages into the log file but strange thing is that same script logging messages are logged in `/var/mail/${user_name}` file. Due to this, system space is full. and script is throwing error of memory.
I am not able to understand why it is logged into `/var/mail/${user_name}` file.

Below is the logging code

```
[[ ${TEST} -eq 1 ]] && echo "${Timestamp}|${Severity}|${ErrorType}|${MsgText}"
echo "${Timestamp}|${Severity}|${MsgGroup}|${VFService}|${Country}|${Partner}|${LiveStatus}|${OMURelevant}|${VisibleForSOC}|${ForwardToOpCo}|${CallOut}|${Node}|${Object}|${Application}|${ErrorType}|${MsgText}" >> ${LOGFILE}
```

Please help on this.

Comment: I doubt if it's possible to say anything without looking at *what* you've created.

Comment: It sends mail to your current user? Like ``echo test | mail $USER``

Comment: thanks Felix Yan..But I didn't use `mail` word in the whole scirpt

Comment: how is this script run? cron?!?

Comment: yes...script is schedule by cron

Comment: So this is the default behavior of cron. The output of the script will be mailed to the user who owns the cron schedule, so it ends up as a mail.